# Hide User Control in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have an usercontrol which is present in all pages of my web app.

I want to hide that user control just in one page.

So I have this user control on my master.master:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/LCSK/LiveSupportChat.ascx" TagPrefix="lc2" TagName="chat" %>
```

... and inside the  i call it:

```
 <lc2:chat runat="server" ID="ClientUserControl" Visible="true" />
```

Then I have my aspx page where I want to hide that userControl.

That aspx page has another master page(diferent from master.master):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LiveSupportChat.aspx.cs" Inherits="TrainReadyV3.LiveSupportChat" MasterPageFile="~/App.Master" %>
```

And in my app.master I have this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="App.master.cs" Inherits="TrainReadyV3.App" MasterPageFile="~/master.Master" %>
```

How can i get acess to the user control from master, and hide it when a user goes to livesupport aspx?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the master page you can do it this way, but I don`t understand something, you have master page in master page or ?

```
foreach (Control a in Page.Master.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control c in Master.Controls)
            {
                if (c.UniqueID == "form1")
                {
                    foreach (Control b in c.Controls)
                    {
                        if (b.UniqueID.Contains("header"))
                        {
                            b.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: my aspx has app.master as masterpage file, and my app.master inherits all from master.master

Comment: well you can place it on the page load to test it but that header on your code maybe will be with other name you must check it

Answer (score 0):

I think the following have a better chance of working:

```
  ContentPlaceHolder cp = this.Master.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as  ContentPlaceHolder;
  Control uc= cp.FindControl("ClientUserControl") as Control;
```

where your main(topmost) masterpage has a contentplaceholder like:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
```

Comment: the first two lines go to master code behind or to aspx code behind?